# How to concatenate columns and column names for each row, excluding a specific value in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df = read.table(text="X1    X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7
C   U   C   D   B   C   C
D   C   B   A   C   D   U
D   C   B   A   C   D   D
C   D   U   U   B   C   D
C   D   B   D   C   U   C
D   C   C   A   B   C   D
U   D   C   U   U   C   C", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to concatenate all columns and their column names for each row separately but the columns with "U" would be excluded. to find out which rows and columns have "U", use

```
which(df == "U", arr.ind=TRUE)
```

the result is expected as:

```
output = read.table(text="'X1 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7' 'C C D B C C'
'X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6'  'D C B A C D'
'X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7' 'D C B A C D D'
'X1 X2 X5 X6 X7'  'C D B C D'
'X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X7'  'C D B D C C'
'X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7'  'D C C A B C D'
'X2 X3 X6 X7'  'D C C C'", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I don't know how to get the expected result without using a loop. Thanks.

Comment: You meant `df != "U"`, right? One easier option is `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`. i.e. `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {i1 <- x!="U"; c(V1=paste(names(x)[i1], collapse=" "), V2= paste(x[i1], collapse=" ")) }))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easier option would be `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
            i1 <- x!="U"
            c(V1=paste(names(x)[i1], collapse=" "),
              V2= paste(x[i1], collapse=" ")) }))
```

To get the values alone, another option is `paste` and then do the `gsub`

```
trimws(gsub("\\s*U", "", do.call(paste, df)))
```

Or as @RHertel mentioned

```
gsub("\\sU|U\\s","",do.call(paste,df))
```

Comment: @RHertel Thank you, I didn't notice it before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more approach using `grepl` which finds the index of the character.

```
res=t(apply(df, 1, function(x)
    c(v1=paste(names(x)[which(grepl("U", x)==F)], collapse = " "),
      v2=paste(x[which(grepl("U", x)==F)], collapse = " "))
    ))
```